# GetVersionInfo return empty result

Tags: powershell-2.0

Same question as [Retrieve Version Info from large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822147/retrieve-version-info-from-large-files), but I'm looking for a solution that will work on PowerShell 2.0.

I've tried from `dir 'path\filename'` to 
`[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('path\filename')`.

And the results are the same:

```
ProductVersion     FileVersion     FileName  
--------------     -----------         
                                   c:\Filename.exe
```

Comment: `[Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo('...')` should work, provided the file in question has version information stored in its extended properties (verify via the *Details* tab in the properties dialog, or [like this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2015/02/22/filtering-files-by-their-metadata-extended-properties/)).

Comment: File description, File version, Product name, Product version have values under the file Details tab. No results in Powershell.  I do get the correct value with a WMI call.

Comment: What WMI call? What does it show? What does the *Details* tab show? Can you enumerate the extended properties with the function I linked to?